# Error storing the result of select for xml into an xml variable (TSQL)

Tags: xml, t-sql

I am having trouble storing the result of a "select for xml" into an xml variable.
I am trying to do something like this:

```
declare @m xml
select @m=(select value from MyTable for xml auto)
select @m as m
```

If MyTable contains only few records then anything is fine but, when MyTable contains more records (Ex:4700) the result is empty.
It's intresting that even for more than 10000 records the select the result is OK:

```
select value from MyTable for xml auto
```

works fine but:

```
select value from MyTable for xml auto, type
```

is empty.

I did something wrong or is it a bug?
Is there any workaround for this? The xml variable is important for me because I want to make some operations later on the xml content using XML-DML. I'm using MSSQL2008 SP1

Please help me!

Comment: It seems to be a bug. It apears on Windows Vista SP1 only(?). Works fine on Win.Server 2003 R2 SP1 and Win.XP SP3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a SQL server issue! It worked fine all time. The bug seems to be in the editor I used: Visual Studio 2008 SP1 T-SQL query editor. Anything is fine using SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

According to this link (referring to their example code):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx

they are using the `SET` command to populate the variable before `SELECT`ing it. DO you get the same error if you do this with your data?